# Is there a Dot NET (C#) library for MS Excel operations (read/write)?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, crud

I'm coding a library from scratch and was wondering if one already exists.

I need to perform the following operations:
- Read all sheets from all excel files in a specified folder and place them in a data set (each sheet from each file in a different data table. And each excel sheet in a different data set)
- A quick efficient way to write one data table to a new excel file in one excel sheet.
- Works on xls and xlsx files.

A link to an open source library would be really helpful.

Comment: I think you'll find that the good libraries here aren't open source.

Answer (score 2):

It's not open source, but I usually find myself using the [Open XML SDK 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx) from Microsoft to perform this type of work.

Comment: OP was looking for XLS support, which I take to mean binary format.

Answer (score 2):

as an alternative to the component you can query a spreadsheet as a "classic" datasource like Sql Server. Create a connection string pointing to the path of your file and use the Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0 provider (it is not available on x64 os, in that case you will have to use third party component to establish the connection). Once this is done you can run sql statements over your .xls .

Here you can find some useful infos : hhttp://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/05/26/2973.aspx

Comment: Interesting, never thought it could be accessed this way. I'd imagine this is the most efficient method than by going cell by cell.

[your link is broken]

Answer (score 0):

[Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) is a good library for handling Excel files.

However, it is not open source.

I have yet to find a good library that is open source for this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at EPPlus: [Codeplex](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).
Note that it only works with .xlsx, is that a problem, or could it work?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code for reading excel file(.xls binary) http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/Excel_DataReader.aspx